# Change Frame Title over a text field

Tags: java

i want to change a Frame title over a Text field in an other Frame.

Now i have a frame1 with Title "Hotelverwaltung 1.0 (Hotel Manta Resort,Pemba/Tansania)" and an other frame2 with a text field.
In this Text field i want to write a new name for the Hotel for example Title "Hotelverwaltung 1.0 (Hotel xxxxx)" .This titel should be shown in frame 1.

Can you please help me in this case?

Comment: Code please.  Can't help you without that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey durbnpoisn ,I use a designer in Netbeans in which i have created a frame.This frame  has a title:  "Hotelverwaltung 1.0 (Hotel Manta Resort,Pemba/Tansania)" .This title i want to change with a texfield in a JDialog.So i enter a new title and press change button.So now i have no code i only want an idea how to realize this

Comment: jTextField_HotelnameAendern.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Frame.setTitle(jTextField_HotelnameAendern.getText());
                
            }
        });
        add(jTextField_HotelnameAendern);
        but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your code however a raw answer can be as follow:

frame2.setTitle(this.textbox1.getText());

Comment: private void jButtonchangeNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
      jTextField_HotelnameAendern.setTitle(this.Frame.getText());} this is my code but Frame is underlined cant find symbol:variable frame

Comment: you ask for changing the Frame title but the code you wrote is changing the textfield title!!! I can not understand